# How do I store data using PhoneGap, HTML/JavaScript, and jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am using HTML and JavaScript to build an iPhone app via PhoneGap.  I want to store data in the app as well.  I know that HTML5 has sessionStorage, localStorage, and Web SQL databases.  However, I haven't been able to figure out if clearing the iPhone Safari cookies and cache would kill any data stored in the app since it's using web storage.  Would deleting the iPhone Safari cache and/or cookies kill the data?

If so, is there any other way to actually store data on the physical device through PhoneGap?  What are some options that I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clearing the phone cache or cookies wont delete the data in the localstorage. that data wont go unless app data is deleted from settings.

for more info u can refer this - [How permanent is local storage on Android and iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750857/how-permanent-is-local-storage-on-android-and-ios)