# Phonegap In App Browser and Local Storage

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, inappbrowser

I am going to create an Android application using HTML5/jQuery and Phonegap In app Browser. I will display web page inside the In app Browser,

I want to implement the functionality that the user only enters his Name when he first time access the application.

I can save value using Phonegap's Local Storage but can't find how to access this value inside In app Browser.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If people aren't capable of giving suggestions or answers that do not involve javascript and/or jquery then STOP REMOVING THE TAGS.  They're perfectly acceptable as the answer may involed javascript communicating with the client application.  Until that's ruled out the tags are relevant.

Comment: @Archer Ummm can we put the `Phonegap` tag here instead of `javascript`. Something I tried and got rejected.

Comment: I am not sure about Android, but Phonegap for iOS actually saves the LocalStorage database under the key 'WebDatabaseDirectory' in user defaults, and I assume the InAppBrowser should be able to access it in some way… hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following documentation for more information

[Is local storage for a Phonegap app on an Android device separate from the built in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184567/is-local-storage-for-a-phonegap-app-on-an-android-device-separate-from-the-built)

Comment: I used this to save and get data in local storage:

`var storage = window.localStorage;
localStorage.myname = "test value";
var name = localStorage.myname;`

and this to call in app browser:

'var ref = window.open('URL', '_blank', 'location=yes');
'

So, i got the value in name variable. So, i wanna ask if i can access this variable inside in app browser.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? i.e. is the storage available to both the in app browser (phonegap) and the device browser?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it but it seems like the inappbrowser and your phone gap app uses different localStorage as if they are two different browser instances.