# Keep user logged in

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I was to keep user logged in (user shouldn't enter username/password every time he uses the app) like in Facebook & Twitter.
I've gone through question & the only way I found is to save username & password then perform login every time the user opens the app
Does Worklight/MobileFirst have a way to keep user logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other Worklight/MobileFirst features that you *may* be interested in looking into...

**Device SSO**

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_device_single_sign_on.html

Single sign-on (SSO) enables users to access multiple resources (that is, applications and adapter procedures) by authenticating only once.
SSO session lasts as long as the session timeout period configured (default 10 minutes).

**User certificate authentication**

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_user_CA.html

Very first time you're asked to authenticate using your authentication realm of choice. At this time your device is enrolled and an x509 certificate is saved on your device.
Every request after that uses an x509 certificate stored on device... so authentication is seamless to the user.
You're asked to reauthenticate only after x509 certificate expires, or is revoked.
Requires a PKI (to manage certificates).  An embedded PKI is provided only for dev/test purposes.
Certificate can be associated with a single app or a family of applications (signed by same identity and belonging to the same group).

**JSONStore**

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore.html

JSONStore is a lightweight, document-oriented storage system that is included as a feature of IBM® MobileFirst Platform Foundation, and enables persistent storage of JSON documents., 
You can store encrypted passwords, but you would need to save some sort of PIN as the password for the store in order to save the password correctly.

**Simple Data Sharing**

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_simple_data_sharing.html

You can store simple data like user id/passwords using simple data sharing.  The data persists after the app is shut down.  You can even share this with other applications in the same family (signed by same identity and belonging to the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a "remember me"-like functionality.
IBM Worklight does not provide this ability built-in. You need to implement it.

You can review past questions about this, like this one: [How to achieve "Remember Me" functionality for both local and remote login pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643591/how-to-achieve-remember-me-functionality-for-both-local-and-remote-login-pages)