# Persistence of local storage in iOS 6.1

Tags: cordova, local-storage

I'm working in a Cordova based mobile application. I'm planning to store data in local storage. I read in net there are some issues with local storage persistence in iOS. Is local storage persists in iOS 6.1 and later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's safe to use it.
I don't have any issues at all.

However, keep in mind that local storage is deleted once you delete your app from the phone.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What about the file storage, do it'll be deleted when I delete the app?

Answer (score 0):

`Local storage` is deleted when `iOS` run out of the memory on device and removes caches - see `Edit` in answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7754409/3158204