# Local storage using Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ionic-framework

I am trying to hook my app up to local storage so that I can have the data saved on the users device and not being reset each time the app is closed. My only issue is I can't figure out to actually link local storages to my array of objects. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have added any code that I believe is relevant.

app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('gas-mileage-tracker', ['ionic', 'ionic.utils', 'gas-mileage-tracker.controllers', 'gas-mileage-tracker.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})
.run(function($localstorage) {
      var mileages = [];
      $localstorage["mileages"] = JSON.stringify(mileages);
      $localstorage.set('name', 'mileages');
      console.log($localstorage.get('name'));
      $localstorage.setObject('post', mileages=[{
        id: 0,
        mpg: 20,
        car: "1998 Toyota 4runner",
        miles_driven: "",
        gallons_added: "",
        gas_station: "Shell"
      }]);
      var post = $localstorage.getObject('post');
      console.log(post);

    })
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

    .state('tab.calculations', {
      url: '/calculations',
      views: {
        'tab-calculations': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-calculations.html',
          controller: 'CalculationsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('tab.mileages', {
      url: '/mileages',
      views: {
        'tab-mileages': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-mileages.html',
          controller: 'MileagesCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('tab.mileage-details', {
      url: '/mileages/:mileageId',
      views: {
        'tab-mileages': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/mileage-details.html',
          controller: 'MileageDetailsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('tab.gas_stations', {
      url: '/gas_stations',
      views: {
        'tab-gas_stations': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-gas_stations.html',
          controller: 'GasStationsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('tab.cars', {
      url: '/cars',
      views: {
        'tab-cars': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-cars.html',
          controller: 'CarsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/mileages');

});
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('gas-mileage-tracker.controllers', [])

.controller('CalculationsCtrl', function($scope, Mileages) {
    $scope.add = function(mileage) {
        Mileages.add(mileage);
    }
})
.controller('MileagesCtrl', function($scope, Mileages) {
    $scope.mileages = Mileages.all();
    $scope.remove = function(mileage) {
        Mileages.remove(mileage);
    };
    $scope.add = function(mileage) {
        Mileages.add(mileage);
    };

})
.controller('MileageDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Mileages) {
    $scope.mileage = Mileages.get($stateParams.mileageId);
})

.controller('GasStationsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Mileages) {
    $scope.mileages = Mileages.all();
    $scope.mileage = Mileages.get($stateParams.mileageId);
})

.controller('CarsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Mileages) {
    $scope.mileages = Mileages.all();
    $scope.mileage = Mileages.get($stateParams.mileageId);
})
```

services.js

```
angular.module('gas-mileage-tracker.services', [])

.factory('Mileages', function() {
    var mileages = [{
    id: 0,
    mpg: 20,
    car: "1998 Toyota 4runner",
    miles_driven: "",
    gallons_added: "",
    gas_station: "Shell"
  }, {
    id: 1,
    mpg: 16,
    car: "2002 Toyota 4runner",
    miles_driven: "",
    gallons_added: "",
    gas_station: "Loaf N' Jug"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    mpg: 18,
    car: "2002 Toyota 4runner",
    miles_driven: "",
    gallons_added: "",
    gas_station: "Conoco"

  }, {
    id: 3,
    mpg: 17,
    car: "1998 Toyota 4runner",
    miles_driven: "",
    gallons_added: "",
    gas_station: "Bradley"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    mpg: 18,
    car: "2002 Toyota 4runner",
    miles_driven: "",
    gallons_added: "",
    gas_station: "Texaco"
  }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return mileages;
    },
    remove: function(mileage) {
      mileages.splice(mileages.indexOf(mileage), 1);
    },
      add: function(mileage) {
        mileage.id = mileages.length;
        mileage.mpg = mileage.miles_driven/mileage.gallons_added
        mileages.push({ 
          editMode: false, 
          id: mileage.id, 
          mpg: mileage.mpg, 
          car: mileage.car,
          gas_station: mileage.gas_station
           }); 
          console.log(mileage); // Log the original mileage 
        console.log(mileages[mileage.id]); // Log the added mileage 
        mileage.mpg= ''; 
        mileage.miles_driven= ''; 
        mileage.gallons_added= ''; 
        mileage.car= ''; 
        mileage.gas_station= '';

    },
    edit: function(mpg) {
      mileage.editMode = true;
      mileages.mpg = mileage.mpg
      console.log(mileage);
    },
    save: function(mpg) {

        mileage.editMode = false;
    },
    get: function(mileageId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < mileages.length; i++) {
        if (mileages[i].id === parseInt(mileageId)) {
          return mileages[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

utils.js

```
angular.module('ionic.utils', [])

.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key, defaultValue) {
      return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: the question is way to broad, please specify what do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: I want to be able to add remove and what not to the database using the functions I currently have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this service to manage, create, retrieve, or delete LocalStorage variables in each of its controllers. I hope it will help.

```
.factory('sessionService',['$http',function($http){
return {
   set:function(key,value){
      return localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(value));
   },
   get:function(key){
     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
   },
   destroy:function(key){
     return localStorage.removeItem(key);
   },
 };
}])
```

Comment: Okay so having that how do I implement that with the add and remove functions I currently have in place?

Comment: @JacobBrauchler Hey, I do not quite understand what you mean

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work using those methods, I need to save certain pieces of data but I can't get it to do that with those functions.

Comment: Certain pieces? What do you mean? that format have that data?

Comment: based on the services I have in place I tried to implement them in the functions you gave me but, the data is not being stored. it would be the format of mileages that you see in my services.js

Comment: I understand it's strange, I keep a lot like you. Try adding each field (id, mpg car) add double quotes, "id": 1, "mpg": 20, etc etc.  Your JSON is invalid https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86644/discussion-between-sioesi-and-jacob-brauchler).

Answer (score 3):

Just to make sure to make more users aware of the fact, that the localstorage doesn't necessarily have to be persistent (on iOS), please take a look at:

[How permanent is local storage on Android and iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750857/how-permanent-is-local-storage-on-android-and-ios)

Therefore I would recommend to use the nativestorage in your wrapper instead:

https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage