# How to login with session using Angular?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, session

login.js

```js
     $http({
              url: 'http://ipadress/login.php',
              method: 'POST',
              data: {
                'var_id': $scope.form.txt_id,
                'var_pass': $scope.form.txt_pass
              }
            }//http
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
mysql_select_db("db");
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$dataJsonDecode = json_decode($data);

$var_id = $dataJsonDecode->var_id;
$var_pass = $dataJsonDecode->var_pass;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_login = '".($id)."' and user_pass = '".md5($pass)."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$resource = mysql_query($sql);
$count_row = mysql_num_rows($resource);

if (!$result) {
    $results = '{"results":"not match"}';
} else {
    $_SESSION["users_login"] = $result["users_login"];
    session_write_close();
    if($count_row > 0){
        $results = '{"results":"match"}';
    } else {
        $results = '{"results":"Error"}';
    }
}
echo $results;
?>
```

```js
$http.get('http://ipaddress/data_user.php')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.results);
        $scope.myData = response.data.results;
      }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

user_data.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['users_login'] == ""){
    $results = '{"results":"Please Login"}';
    echo $results;
}
else{
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
    mysql_select_db("db");
    mysql_query( "SET NAMES UTF8" );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users_login = '".$_SESSION["users_login"]."' ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $count_row = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count_row > 0){
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $rows[] = $result;
        }
        $data = json_encode($rows);
        $totaldata = sizeof($rows);
        $results = '{"results": '.$data.'}';
    }
    echo $results;
}
?>
```

I have problem with login. My `$results = please login`.

Comment: why you tagged ionic here?

Comment: sorry this is first post.

Comment: Can you reccommend me.

Comment: **Do not put this live on the internet**. It needs rewriting, and you will get hacked in short order if you put this live. Your database queries are susceptible to SQL injection, and your password hashes are easily reversible, since you're using a fast hash with no salt. Unless you really know what you are doing, you should always use a good quality library to handle user accounts and authentication. Your database library is also no longer supported by the PHP core team.

Comment: Can you recommend libary? I'm new programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check what `$result["users_login"]` contains..
You are getting the `please login` because you don't have the session data.
I am not sure about your approach, but don't mix php session and Ionic, You can create a kind of API to check user credentials from your ionic App, or else handle it in the ionic app.
Session normally used in websites to pass data through out the page, not for API calls. Think of scenario 10 users access your app simultaneously, How you going to use the `Session` to verify them?

My advise is, instead of using PHP sessions, you can handle your sessions inside your app using the session storage
[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088399/ionic-how-to-store-session-token-as-globally-for-app-accessible-variable). There are plenty of plugin available. OR you can create your as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31927247/7105521)
Good Luck!!