# Cordova LocalStorage persists data even after app uninstall

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage, persistence

I am using the LocalStorage in my cordova-based android app to store some information, but I have recently experienced something very weird. **The LocalStorage persists even after I uninstall the app and install it again!**

As far as I can understand, this should not be the case. Everywhere I read people say something like "*LocalStorage is deleted when you clear app data from settings, or the app in uninstalled*".

This has made me wonder a few things; How persistent is the LocalStorage? Does it persist between applications? Is it possible that I have some other cordova app installed which would be able to access the same LocalStorage?

### More importantly; Is LocalStorage safe? Can I be sure no other application (or "cracker") could access that information?

I have only seen this behaviour on android.

This is not what I expect, or want, to happen. Is there some way I can force the data to be deleted when the user uninstalls the app?

Some info is found here:

[How permanent is local storage on Android and iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750857/how-permanent-is-local-storage-on-android-and-ios)

---

- Android 6.0.1 (cyanogenmod on Samsung galaxy s3 GTI9300)
- Cordova version 6.3.0
- Using cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.7.2
- Cordova android platform version 5.1.1
- Plugin list:

  - com.keepe.cardio 1.0.9 "CardIO"
  - custom.version.of.cordova.camerapreview 1.0.1 "CameraPreview"
  - cordova-plugin-backbutton 0.3.0 "Backbutton"
  - cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
  - cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.7.2 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
  - cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.2.0 "Custom URL scheme"
  - cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
  - cordova-plugin-file 4.1.1 "File"
  - cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1 "File Transfer"
  - cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.7 "Google Firebase Plugin"
  - cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.1.0 "Geolocation"
  - cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.1 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
  - cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.3.0 "InAppBrowser"
  - cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix 1.0.1 "iOS LongPress Fix"
  - cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.0 "Network Information"
  - cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.1 "StatusBar"
  - cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.0 "Vibration"
  - cordova-plugin-webserver 1.0.3 "CordovaWebServer"
  - cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
  - cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.1 "SocialSharing"

Answer (score 11):

I also had a same kind of problem you can find a answer from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867189/localstorage-data-already-there-after-i-uninstalled-and-installed-the-ionic-app/41870759#41870759). It was worked for me.

**These are the steps I followed.**

- After project build go to path: `platforms\android\`
- Then in `AndroidManifest.xml` file add the followings to  application tag

> `android:allowBackup="false" and android:fullBackupContent="false"`

eg: 
 In my case it is look like this.

```
<application android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupContent="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
```

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: I got you, thanks. I added some information it will help. :)